# Node-REDで開いているSheet以外の処理実行を止められますか

Tags: bluemix

Sheetをたくさん開いてフローを複数作って開発していると右端のdebugのところに表示されるメッセージがどのフローから来ているのか分かりにくく紛らわしいです

debugノードで右端のボタンで表示のオン／オフができるのは知っていますが
作業中のSheet以外はすべて処理の実行をオフにすることはできないのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

確かに選択的にオン/オフできると良さそうですね。
残念ながら現在の仕様ではシートごとに処理を停止するような機能はありません。

> Sheetをたくさん開いてフローを複数作って開発していると右端のdebugのところに表示されるメッセージがどのフローから来ているのか分かりにくく紛らわしいです

これについては、debugコンソールのメッセージをクリックするとそのメッセージを出力したdebugノードが赤の破線で囲まれて表示されるので、それで確認することが可能です。もしそのdebugノードが作業中のシートとは別のシートに存在していたとしても、シートが自動的に切り替わってくれます。